# NSPredicate With FUNCTION Not Working

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, cllocation

My predicate keeps on crashing my app with the message Unsupported function expression `FUNCTION(SELF, "filterDistanceWithLatitude:" , latitude, longitude`). Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
- (void)setUpFetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"NextTime"]; //Retrieve data for the place entity
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]]; //How to sort it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil]; //Puts the data in a NSFetchedResultsController which is oddly located in CoreDataTableViewController //Puts the data in a NSFetchedResultsController which is oddly located in CoreDataTableViewController
    self.filtered = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION(self, 'filterByDistanceWithLatitude:', latitude, longtitude) > 20"];
    self.filtered = [self.filtered filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

- (double)filterByDistanceWithLatitude:(NSNumber *)latitude andLongitude:(NSNumber *)longitude
{
    CLLocationDegrees latitudeCoor = [latitude doubleValue]; //Puts the latitude into a NextTime object.
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeCoor = [longitude doubleValue]; //Puts the longtitude into a NextTime object.

    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitudeCoor longitude:longitudeCoor];
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.currentLocation.latitude longitude:self.currentLocation.longitude];

    NSNumber *distance = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2]];

    return [distance doubleValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fetch request for a (SQL based) Core Data store cannot use Objective-C based predicates or sort descriptors. You can only filter on attributes stored in the data base.

Here is the relevant documentation from the "Core Data Programming Guide":

- [Fetching Managed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW3):

> You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties
>   (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory
>   yourself). ... To summarize, though, if you execute a fetch directly, you should
>   typically not add Objective-C-based predicates or sort descriptors to
>   the fetch request. Instead you should apply these to the results of
>   the fetch.

- [Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11):

> There are some interactions between fetching and the type of store.
>   ... The SQL store, on the other hand, compiles the predicate and sort
>   descriptors to SQL and evaluates the result in the database itself.
>   This is done primarily for performance, but it means that evaluation
>   happens in a non-Cocoa environment, and so sort descriptors (or
>   predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work.

Comment: So is there another way to approach this using NSPredicate

Comment: @gsapienza: Not in combination with a fetched results controller. But you could fetch all objects (using `NSArray *allObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:...]`, without a restricting predicate), and then apply the filter to the resulting array (e.g. `NSArray *filteredObjects = [allObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]`.

Comment: Updated the code for that, still have the same error. Is my predicate formatted correctly?

Comment: @gsapienza: I have seen "FUNCTION(...)" only with `NSExpression`, but not with `NSPredicate`. I would use a block-based predicate (`predicateWithBlock`) to filter the array.

Answer (score 0):

'filterDistanceWithLatitude:' probably should be 'filterByDistanceWithLatitude:'