# 'Unable to parse the format string "function == %@"' when using NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to search an `NSArray` via the '`function`' attribute. The output when I print the array on the console is as follows:

```
<__NSArrayI 0xa523b40>(
{
    category = "010-T";
    description = "<h3>Opleidingen</h3>";
    function = "T-r";
    name = "Michal Jordan";
    photo = "http://dws.com/34.jpg";
},
{
    category = "010-T";
    description = "abcd";
    function = "AB";
    name = "Pvt MSK";
    photo = "http://test.com/3.jpg";
},
{
    category = "010-T";
    description = "def";
    function = "T-r";
    name = "Sanu M";
    photo = "http://abc.com/1.jpg";
}
)
```

This code, which searches by '`category`', works:

```
NSString *categoryStr = @"010-T";
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[myarr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@",categoryStr]]];
```

But when I tried with the following code (searching by `function`), an exception was thrown:

```
NSString *functionStr = @"T-r";
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[myarr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"function == %@",functionStr]]];
```

The exception was:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "function == %@"'
```

So it seems here, that `function` is a reserved keyword.

I tried the following code, wrapping `function` with single quotes, but the result was that `arr` had 0 objects.

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[myarr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"'function' == %@",functionStr]]];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps try "self.function==[cd]%@" assuming its an array of custom classes.

Comment: yeah, it's interesting, it is array with keyvalue pair, and your later solution gives me error like: Unable to parse the format string "self.function==[cd]%@" ,, same right?

Comment: one another thing, seems function is reserved word, if I try with "name" keyword, it is working..

Comment: It seems like it's impossible to have `function` in your predicate. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292582/nspredicate-with-function-not-working and here http://moottoot.blogspot.it/2008/01/oooh-nspredicate-functions.html

To be precise, you can have `function`, but it should really be a function.

Comment: hmm , thanks @anticyclope for opening a door, I will go through this. thank you again..

Comment: @PravatMaskey I edited your question to try to make the English flow a bit better, and hopefully be easier for most to understand quickly and search for. I hope I represented everything well and didn't change your meaning at all. Interesting question by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) states that "Predicate expressions in Cocoa are represented by instances of NSExpression." Note that `NSExpression` provides a syntax whereby one can invoke method calls via the `FUNCTION` keyword. [The docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) define the syntax as `FUNCTION(receiver, selectorName, arguments, ...)`. While I find no reference to this in any documentation, it appears this feature excludes the use of the literal word function in other contexts.

Fortunately, you can build your predicate format string in an alternative way using the `%K` format specifier, which is used for key names. For example, `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"function", @1]` will not throw an exception and will work correctly. See it in action in the following code:

```
    NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"otherKey": @1, @"function" : @2};
    NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"otherKey": @2, @"function" : @1};
    NSArray *array = @[dict1, dict2];
    NSPredicate *otherKeyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",@"otherKey", @1];
    NSArray *filteredByOtherKey = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:otherKeyPredicate];
    NSPredicate *functionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"function", @1];
    NSArray *filteredByFunction = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:functionPredicate];
    NSLog(@"filteredByOtherKey = %@", filteredByOtherKey);
    NSLog(@"filteredByFunction = %@", filteredByFunction);
```

We get the following output on the console:

```
filteredByOtherKey = (
        {
        function = 2;
        otherKey = 1;
    }
)
filteredByFunction = (
        {
        function = 1;
        otherKey = 2;
    }
)
```

Constructing your predicates this way may be slightly more work but will prevent these types of conflicts in the future. A good practice moving forward is to restrict the format string to containing only format specifiers and predicate syntax, finalizing the prediate's expression string at run time.

Comment: yes, this is the answer.. NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",
        attributeName, attributeValue]; ,,, thank you it solves my problem

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *functionStr = @"T-r";
NSArray *arr = [myarr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(function == %@)",functionStr]];


Here myarr is NSMutableArray.
Try with this code.
```