# NSPredicate query issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate, predicate

I am facing a difficulty to create a `NSPredicate` to fetch some data from my entity,

My Entity contains a field called phoneNumber . This field can be either in international or local format. Let's give for example it contains now the number 050654637.

Now when I have an international number and try to fetch the entity to get the fields that contains my number,it return empty (let's say I am trying to fetch the number 97150654637).

My predicate is the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumber == %@   || phoneNumber ENDSWITH[cd] %@", internationalNumber, internationalNumber];
```

which will not meet any of my case because it should be that the internationalNumber ends with the field phoneNumber without the starting '0'.

So what would be the predicate to use in this case?

Comment: I'd convert it to block-base predicate – those are much easier to maintain.

Comment: @holex can you please help me with it? i never use it before, and i am trying  to use predicateWithBlock but without any success. Can you please help me with forming  predicate?

Comment: you can use [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumber ENDSWITH[cd] %@", [internationalNumber substringFromIndex:1]];

Comment: but i should substring the one in the dAtabase and not the international number.
what i have in core data : 050654637
my number: 97150654637
when i search for 97150654637 if exist in the core data, it should return true because i already have it but in local format

Comment: @IphoneUser, if you can describe exactly what you'd like to filter and how (that is a bit ambiguous in the post currently), it will be a child's play to create a correct predicate – and I'm happy to help on you.

Comment: @holex: Note that block-based predicates cannot be used with Core Data fetch requests. (And since OP is talking about *entities* I assume that the question is about Core Data.)

Comment: @MartinR So what should be my NSPredicate ((

Comment: @MartinR, I have never heard or experienced such limitation of the predicates. the predicates are predicates, no matter how you define them... but I guess your next step is that presenting a link to me about this _"cannot"_ limitation.

Comment: @holex: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13292820/1187415 and the links given there.

Comment: i have an international number(97150654637) ..i would like to fetch in the database if this number exist. The result should be true even if the number in the database(050654637) is in local format

Comment: Any urgent help? I should meet my deadline soon(( ..i am stuck on this issue from the beginning of the day!

Comment: @IphoneUser, maybe MartinR can help on you, after he highlighted you might not be able to use block-based predicates – if you are really using Core-Data.

Comment: @holex .. yes i am using Core-Data

Comment: Probably because your number is an NSNumber? If you save it as a string it should work...

Comment: @holex thanks for your time and trying to help me anw :)

Comment: @DanielGalasko it is already a string! but i am searching for ( 97150654637) in the database, and the database contains the string number (050654637) ! that's why the predicate is returning an empty array

Comment: Then your predicate construction needs to be a bit more intelligent and determine whether the string prefix is an international code, if it is then it should remove it.

Comment: Whatever way you do it, you need to be able to realize which part of the string is the code and which is the number

Comment: @DanielGalasko exactly but which i don't have control on it, the server replies the number without knowing if it is international or not so i can't remove the country code part. That's why i am trying to solve it in a predicate