# NSPredicate with a function

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How can i use NSPredicate with a function?
So for example, i have a date and this function:

```
let date= NSDate() 
func isSameDays(date1:NSDate?, _ date2:NSDate?) -> Bool { //Code }
```

Then i have an array of objects with has a date property:

```
let arr = [o1, o2, o3] that i want to filter
```

How can i use NSPredicate to filter with my function?

```
isSameDays(object.date, date)?
```

Here i dont know how to apply this function to NSPredicate. I tried with a block but im not sure how this can be done.
**Note that i want at final to have a NSPredicate using isSameDays.**

I want to pass to getObjects also a Predicate with this 3 constraints.

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "user == %@", argumentArray: [user])
let p2 = ...?
let finalP = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2])

    let visits = database.getObjects(Visit) 
        .filter { visit -> Bool in
            return (
                statuses.contains(visit.visitStatus)
                    && isSameDays(visit.dateVisit, date)
                    && visit.user == user
            )
        }
```

Comment: Show how you tried with the block

Comment: @Wain basically i want instead of filtering the ALL the results from the database, i want to send a predicate with those conditions, and not get ALL the objects from the database and then filtering here.

Comment: Is this for a Core Data fetch request? In that case you are out of luck, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/13292820/1187415.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering, Realm
supports a limited list of predicates, and function-based predicates
are not on that list.

To retrieve objects from a certain day, something like

```
NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ && date < %@", startDate, endDate)
```

should work, where `startDate` and `endDate` are computed as the
beginning of that day and the beginning of the next day.